# How to add data to MySQL database from within a loop in python? Getting: OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql

My python script is attempting to fetch data for a number of stock tickers.
Basically, like so:

```
for ticker in ticker_list
  [fetch data]
  [call fxn extract_data_and_write_to_database]
```

The sql portion of fxn extract_data_and_write_to_database (each ticker can have multiple rows of fetched data, and this fxn loops through each row, extracts data and writes to database. I don't think the error relates to this inner loop, as I can run this inner loop w/o error. It's when I introduce the outer `for` loop that I have the error):

```
 val = ([variables that correspond to db table columns])
 mycursor.execute(sql, val) # the sql statement is specified outside of the `for` loop
 mydb.commit()
```

I suspect the error is related to the sql portion that is inside the loop because the script gets thru the outer `for` loop once and successfully writes data for first ticker into database table. It's on the second ticker that I receive the error (before any data for second ticker is written into db table).

Full error:
OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 10038 An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

What is the correct way to write to a database table inside of a loop?

Comment: It is difficult to tell without knowing how you fetch data and how your sql is.  But base on the error message, you lost connection to MySQL while you run sql statement.  Did you connect to the database server?  That is did you do db = MySQLdb.connect(host, username, password, database), and mycusor = db.cursor().  And this has to do outside the loop.

Comment: Yes, this is all done before the loop:   `mydb = mysql.connector.connect([host, username, pw, database])`; `mycursor = mydb.cursor()`

Comment: I figured it out. I had `mydb.close()` in the `for ticker in ticker_list` loop, so the database connection is closed after the first time through the `for` loop. And since `mycursor = mydb.cursor()` is before/outside the `for` loop, when the code comes through the `for` loop the second time, the db connection is closed, so `mycursor.execute` throws an exception. To resolve, I moved `mydb.close()` outside and after the `for` loop, so it only runs after all tickers have been cycled through.

Comment: From a 'proper' database management perspective, not sure if the above resolution is optimal (i.e., open connection prior to loop, close connection after all cycles through loop are completed), or if it's better to open the connection inside the loop before writing to database, the close the connection inside the loop after writing to database. I guess my resolution (open and close connection once for entire script execution) is safe from data loss since `mydb.commit()` is executed inside the loop?

Comment: You generally should use 'open db connection;, 'get cursor', 'run sql', 'loop the result by fetching all data', 'update database if needed', 'end loop', then close connection.  The purpose is to reduce the number of open and close db connection since they are quite expensive. You also should try to reduce number of cursor.  Finally, you should do commit as soon as possible.